# extract youtube iframe src attribute using preg_match_all

Tags: regex, youtube, preg-match-all

I'm using the following regex to capture the entire src attribute using preg_match_all:

```
<iframe.*src=\"(.*)\".*><\/iframe>
```

I'm now looking for a way to capture the src attribute (including parameters) only if the url contains either youtube or vimeo. My attempt failed miserably:

```
<iframe.*src=.*(?:youtube|vimeo).*>\/iframe>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

many thanks,

devin

Comment: You are missing a left angle <

Comment: Split the two tasks: 1) retrieve the src content, 2) analyze that string (with another regex or other parser tecniques)

Comment: Use an XPath query: `//iframe/@src[contains(.,"youtube") or contains(.,"vimeo")]`. Don't use regex to parse html.

Comment: With regex you can do something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/wdRJB0/1).

Comment: Thank you for the guidance!